# Root URL appended to domain on NGINX and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm pretty new to NGINX and web servers in general.

I've been trying to install WordPress on NGINX and I've been experiencing an issue where my root directory is appended to my domain when I go search for the domain. I believe this has to do with how NGINX is configured for that domain. Here's the code I've used for the configuration:

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/example.com;
        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

This results in my outputted URL being:

```
http://www.example.com/var/www/example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php
```

Another thing to note. When I edit the `wp-load.php` and change:

`$path = wp_guess_url() . '/wp-admin/setup-config.php';`

to:

`$path = '/wp-admin/setup-config.php';`

The URL works.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Save this as config

```
{
    "listeners": {
        "127.0.0.1:8090": {
            "application": "script_index_php"
        },
        "127.0.0.1:8091": {
            "application": "direct_php"
        }
    },

    "applications": {
        "script_index_php": {
            "type": "php",
            "processes": {
                "max": 20,
                "spare": 5
            },
            "user": "www-data",
            "group": "www-data",
            "root": "/var/www/html/example.com",
            "script": "index.php"
        },
        "direct_php": {
            "type": "php",
            "processes": {
                "max": 5,
                "spare": 0
            },
            "user": "www-data",
            "group": "www-data",
            "root": "/var/www/html/example.com",
            "index": "index.php"
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration creates two NGINX Unit applications, one for each URL scheme – the web application and the administration panel.

Using the NGINX Unit script parameter instead of the index parameter means that requests for pages that are not found use the main index.php script in WordPress. For more information, see the NGINX Unit documentation for PHP application objects.

To scale your application, change the IP addresses and ports accordingly.

Run this curl command to load the configuration:

```````
$ curl -X PUT --data-binary @/var/www/wordpress/wordpress.config --unix-socket /run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config

``````



````
```````